# AsyncTask Thread_Pool_Executor on Android API <11

Tags: android, android-asynctask, compatibility

Im trying to allow my app to run on older versions of Android, Specifically API 10.

I've downloaded the support packages and used them to solve a few problems but im struggling to fix this one:

> Field requires API level 11 (current min is 10):
>   android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

The Thread_Pool_Executor method was only added in API 11.

Is there any way i can use this in API 10 or do i have to revert back to:

```
myAsyncTask().execute();
```

instead of:

```
myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

If so how do i check the API level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Step #1: Set your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 11 or higher.

Step #2: Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine your API level, to use `executeOnExecutor()` only on newer Android devices.

For example, you could have this static utility method somewhere:

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  static public <T> void executeAsyncTask(AsyncTask<T, ?, ?> task, T... params) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    }
    else {
      task.execute(params);
    }
  }
```

Then, to execute a task, just call `executeAsyncTask()`, passing it your `AsyncTask` instance and whatever parameters you want passed into your `doInBackground()` method. `executeAsyncTask()` will choose `executeOnExecutor()` on API Level 11+ or use `execute()` on older devices.

Comment: Does it matter where in the file the @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) goes? I made a similar function and eclipse put it above my class definition.

Comment: @clairharrison: That will work, though in general you want to put `@TargetApi()` at the method level. You can have multiple methods with the `@TargetApi()` annotation.

Comment: Followed your steps
1. Set project build target to api level 19.
2. Checked the api level and accordingly called the execute or executeOnExecutor()
3. But I need to clean my project every time before running else it complains "Field requires API level 11 (current min is 8): 
  android.os.AsyncTask#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR"
M I doing something wrong ? Thanks

Comment: @VihaanVerma: "I doing something wrong ?" -- you will not get that error if you check the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` value as shown in the answer, then mark the method as having `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`.

Comment: Now there is an `AsyncTaskCompat` class in the support-v4 library. You can use that as well: `AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(YourAsyncTask);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful template method  that I add to my AsyncTasks all the time:

```
public class MyClass extends AsyncTask <MyInput<Type1>, MyProgress<Type2>, MyResult<Type3>> {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void start(MyInput<Type1> params) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
          this.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
        } else {
           this.execute(params);
        }
    }
}
```

By calling `MyClass.start(params)`, I get the following benefits:

1. the ugly details of different platform version dependencies are hidden from the user
2. the mechanics of using the THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR are hidden from the user.